# jquery second alternation not running in on(click) - open/close button

Tags: jquery

I always get so confused with open/close buttons.

This is probably the wrong way about going about it - but I cant seem to get the second alternations to run.

Is there something else I should be using? Thanks

```
$(currentSlideHtmlObject).find('.openSpec').on('click',

    function (e){

        e.preventDefault();

        $techSpec.animate({
            left : '-' + $techSpec.outerWidth() + 'px'
        });

    },
    function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $techSpec.animate({
            left : '0px'
        });

    }

);
```

Comment: I thought double handlers worked with 'hover' only...

Comment: Yep, that's the problem. It should work on hover. If you really need a click event, you have to set something to check if it's open (to close), or if it's closed (to open).

Comment: @Onheiron: There's `toggle` as well.

Comment: @7th - yeah I did that originally - setting panelOpen = false, but its playing up every time for me. Because I'm using it on a slider, it works first time, but if navigate through slides, and do it again, it opens and closes it. I made a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/X34XJ/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), not `on`:

```
$("#target").toggle(
  function() {
    console.log("On");
  },
  function() {
    console.log("Off");
  }
);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ozelox/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ozelox/1/edit)

Comment: See toggle is ideal - but because I am using it in a slider, it works first time, but if I navigate through the slide, and then try it again, it opens and closes it, but if I then navigate through the slider and try it again, it opens, closes, then opens it again. And if I use toggle, the first click does nothing. I made a fiddle of my problem... http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/X34XJ/6/

Comment: I marked your question as right cause it technically is a right answer. I have opened another question with my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212114/jquery-open-close-function-within-slider-works-first-time-but-second-time-ru